# Recursive function-Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, methods

Can someone explain what's happening in this code. The code terminates only when -1 is passed. Before that it keeps asking for user input. And only after termination, it prints multiples of 3 from the input values. I am confused where all of the values of x are stored before termination.

```
public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        multipleThree(in);


    }//end of main
    public static  void multipleThree(Scanner in) {
        
        System.out.println("Enter the list(-1 to terminate):");
        int x = in.nextInt();
        if (x == -1) {
            return;
        } else {
            multipleThree(in);
            if (x % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println(x + " is divisible by 3");

        }//end of else
      }//end of method
    }//end of class
```

Comment: every time a method is called, some memory is reserved for its variables and parameters (often called a frame) - so each call has its own version of the variables - since `int x` declares a variable inside the method, this is saved in that memory (frame). Not only relevant for recursive calls, but key for working of recursive methods. [since output is done after the call to `multipleThree`, it will only be executed after the call(s) return]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused where all of the values of x are stored before termination.

They are stored on the *call stack*.

In the beginning, the call stack only has `main`. Then `main` calls `multipleThree`. This pushes a new frame onto the call stack. The frame will store things about where this call to `multipleThree` has progressed to, what local variables there are, etc.

Let's say you entered 3. `x`, which is stored on the frame that is currently the top of the stack. The `else` branch gets executed, and `multipleThree` gets called again, so a new frame gets pushed onto the call stack. Note that we are not done with the first call to `multipleThree` yet. We can come back to it when we finished executing this second call to `multipleThree`. Remember that the 3 you entered is still stored on the call stack.

Let's say you entered 5 next, the same thing happens - the number 5 gets stored on the top of the stack, then a new frame gets pushed as you call `multipleThree` again (this is now the third time).

Finally, you enter -1. At this point, the stack looks like this:

```
multipleThree (x = -1)
multipleThree (x = 5)
multipleThree (x = 3)
main
```

You can see this in the debugger on your IDE. e.g. in IntelliJ IDEA

[image]

Because you entered -1, this call to `multipleThree` actually finishes because it reaches the `return` statement. The top of the stack now gets popped, and we go back to executing the *second* call to `multipleThree`. The stack now looks like this:

```
multipleThree (x = 5)
multipleThree (x = 3)
main
```

In the second call, remember that x is 5 - not divisible by 3, so we don't do anything. Now we are done with the second call to `multipleThree`, so the stack gets popped again:

```
multipleThree (x = 3)
main
```

Now we *finally* go back to executing the first call to `multipleThree`, when `x` is 3. 3 is divisible by 3, so we print it. Now we are done with the first call of `multipleThree` so we pop *it* off the stack too.